# write java wrapper

Tags: java, spring

1.this is how my dao class look like where the transaction code keep repeat for every method. possible to put these snippet code in super class so that i do no need to repeat below code all the time? any elaborate how to do this?

2.if there is a need to put the snippet in super.class. should the super.class be static?

```
 for (int i = 0; i < NUM_RETRIES; i++) {
     pm.currentTransaction().begin();

     <all my code will be here>

     try {
         pm.currentTransaction().commit();
         break;

     } catch (JDOCanRetryException ex) {
         if (i == (NUM_RETRIES - 1)) { 
             throw ex;
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: So let me get this straight - you're repeating **the same code** in a loop multiple times assuming that transaction that failed once will succeed next time? They have a name for that: http://www.quotationspage.com/quote/26032.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing only the "extract to superclass" issue, you could:

In your base class put:

```
public abstract Object doTransaction();

public abstract Object executeTransaction(some params){
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_RETRIES; i++) {
     pm.currentTransaction().begin();

     this.doTransaction();

     try {
         pm.currentTransaction().commit();
         break;

     } catch (JDOCanRetryException ex) {
         if (i == (NUM_RETRIES - 1)) { 
             throw ex;
         }
     }
 }
}
```

In your derived class, redefine doTransaction method

```
public Object doTransaction() {

 //access database and stuff;
}
```

Please adjust the return types and parameters accordingly.

Note that there's nothing static (static methods cant be overridden), its just an implementation of the [template method pattern.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)

Comment: example in dao, i have method   public List<String> getSomething(){ 
    //how to call doTransaction of base class?
  }

Comment: if you need to explicitly call the getSOmething() method on your base class (from a derived instance), just do super.getSomething()

Comment: tom can explain more how i put this into dao.   my dao extends base class?

Comment: from your example, it seem that i can only call doTraction() one time in the dao class

Comment: Yes, your dao extends a base class.

Comment: what i looking for is like below -- >  class testDao extends BaseClass{  public List<String> getSomething(){     return doTEmplate.getSomething(); };      public void saveToDB(){  doTemplate.doSave();        }   }    //something similar to spring, but i interested to know how the backend work